# loading admob ad in android app

Tags: android, admob

Admob ad is not showing in the layout.My code is

```
layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("MY_UNIT_ID");
    adView.loadAd(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onAdLoaded();
            layout.addView(adView,0);
        }
    });
```

whats wrong in this? But when i `remove` the `AdListener` from class then it is showing. Pls help. thanks

Comment: @ParagChauhan he said if he removes adlistener then it's working fine!

Comment: @ Parag Chauhan i added correct unit id of ad from admob site.  "MY_UNIT_ID" just was example

Answer (score 0):

Don't attempt to add the AdView into the layout onAdLoaded. Just add it when you created the ad. Ie

```
layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("MY_UNIT_ID");

layout.addView(adView,0);

adView.loadAd(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Play with layout visibility it should work**

```
 layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("MY_UNIT_ID");
        adView.loadAd(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
        layout.addView(adView);
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```